How to get Razor page folder path?
I am using ASP.NET Core 8 Razor pages. I have a few pages in a same route folder like the following:

/App/ADMIN/Order/Details.cshtml
/App/ADMIN/Order/Listing.cshtml
/App/ADMIN/Order/Print.cshtml

I can get the page URL with the following code:
string path = $"{_httpContext.Request.PathBase}{_httpContext.Request.RouteValues["Page"]}";

When I am on a page like /App Name/ADMIN/Order/Details, from code-behind, is there any function to get its path /App Name/ADMIN/Order/?
If not, I have to get the last index of / and remove Details from the string.
Please advise. Thanks.

You could try use
    var path = context.Request.Path.Value;
    var result = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)?.Replace("\\", "/");


